# Custom type in GraphQL mutation

Tags: ecmascript-6, graphql, graphql-js

I am using [GraphQL js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js).I want to implement One-to-many association in it.I have two types **user** and **Office**.One user has many offices.

**userType:**

```
var graphql = require('graphql');
const userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'user',
fields :()=>{
var officeType=require('./officeSchema');
return {
  _id: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLID
  },
  name: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLString
  },
  age: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLString
  },
  office:{
    type:officeType
  }
};
}
 });
module.exports=userType;
```

**officeSchema:**

```
const officeType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'office',
fields:()=> {
var userType = require('./userSchema');
return {
  _id: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLID
  },
  room: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLString
  },
  location: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLString
  },
  users: {
    type: new graphql.GraphQLList(userType),
    resolve: (obj,{_id}) => {
     fetch('http://0.0.0.0:8082/office/user/'+obj._id, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(function(res) {return res}); 
  }
  }
 };
 }
});
```

Now the mutation code is as follows:

```
const Adduser = {
type: userType,
args: {
    name: {
        type: graphql.GraphQLString
    },
    age: {
        type: graphql.GraphQLString
    }

},
resolve: (obj, {
    input
}) => {

}
};
const Addoffice = {
type: OfficeType,
args: {
     room: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        location: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        users: {
            type: new graphql.GraphQLList(userInputType)
        }
},
resolve: (obj, {
    input
}) => {

}
};
const Rootmutation = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Rootmutation',
fields: {
    Adduser: Adduser,
    Addoffice: Addoffice
}
});
```

This code is throwing error as

**Rootmutation.Addoffice(users:) argument type must be Input Type but got: [user].**

I want to add the actual fields in database as well as associated tables' fields but couldn't figure out the problem.

**Updated:**

**1-Added GraphQLInputObjectType:**

```
const officeInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({
name: 'officeinput',
fields: () => {
    return {
        room: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        location: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        }
    }
 }
});
const userInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({
name: 'userinput',
fields: () => {
    return {
        name: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        },
        age: {
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
        }
    }
  }
});
```

**2-Added userinputtype instead of usertype in AddOffice.**

Now the error is

```
 Rootmutation.Addoffice(user:) argument type must be Input Type but got: userinput.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you provided `userType` as one of the argument types for the `Addoffice` mutation. `userType` cannot be an argument type. Instead, you must use an input type.

There are two object types: output and input types. Your `userType` and `officeType` are **output** types. You need to create an **input** type using `GraphQLInputObjectType` [[docs](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlinputobjecttype)]. It will likely have very similar fields. You can use that as a type on your argument field.

```
const userInputType = new graphql.GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInput',
  fields () => {
    return {
      _id: {
        type: graphql.GraphQLID
      },
      // ...
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: changed code according to your suggestion.kindly have a look what i am doing wrong now?